# compare different datasets with stacked bar graphs in R

Tags: r

I need to compare two different methods that each of them has 3 different results in one graph with using stacked bar style.

I want to draw a plot so that x axis shows the experiment and y axis shows results. and each bar fills with 3 results in stacked bar format.

```
experiment method resuult1 result2 result3
1            m1      1        2       3 
1            m2      4        5       6
2            m1      7        8       9
2            m2     10        11      12
3            m1     13        14      15
3            m2     16        17      18
```

Comment: Are you asking *how to visualize this kind of data* (which might be better at CrossValidated), or do you have a specific plot in mind and want to know *how to do it in R* (in which case it would be good if you could add an example plot)?

Comment: I want to draw a plot so that x axis shows the experiment and y axis shows results. and each bar fills with 3 results in stacked bar format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data:

```
dataset <- data.frame(
    experiment = c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
    method = c("m1","m2","m1","m2","m1","m2"),
    result1 = seq(1,16,by=3),
    result2 = seq(2,17,by=3),
    result3 = seq(3,18,by=3))
```

We first need to shift your data into a slightly different format:

```
foo <- t(as.matrix(dataset[,c("result1","result2","result3")]))
bar <- cbind(foo[,1:2],NA,foo[,3:4],NA,foo[,5:6])
```

Look at `bar` to understand what's happening here. Next, we plot and add some axis annotation:

```
baz <- barplot(height=bar,beside=FALSE,
  legend.text=rownames(bar),args.legend=list(x="topleft",inset=0.05))
axis(1,at=baz[c(1,2,4,5,7,8)],labels=dataset[,"method"],tick=FALSE)
axis(1,at=c(mean(baz[1:2]),mean(baz[4:5]),mean(baz[7:8])),
  labels=paste("Experiment",1:3),tick=FALSE,line=2)
```

[image: stacked and grouped barplot]

Comment: thank you. It is exactly what I wanted but could you get this one with ggplot2 package?

Comment: How we can get the dataset from a file and don't make it like this?

Comment: ggplot2 will almost certainly be able to do this, but to be honest, I have never managed to get comfortable with it, so I do everything with base R. You can read your data from a file using `read.table()`, which will give you a `data.frame` like the one I used - look at its help page by typing `?read.table`.